# Date Time formats, change formats.

Tags: php, mysql, database, formats

I have a TIMESTAMP in the database for pages, so in this format `$d="2011-01-03 12:53:22"`

And when i try to send that through `date("c",$d)` I only get `1970-01-01T10:33:31+10:00`

I have read in the php manual that date("c",THIS) must be an INT so what do i use to get the int from "2011-01-03 12:53:22"??

Comment: i find using mysql's DATE_FORMAT() more convenient than using php for formatting

Comment: @Dagon: Okay then, how do you get the date("c") equivalent??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget to convert the date string to timestamp when sending for date function

```
date('c', strtotime($d));
```

Comment: Thanks but I found out about `strtotime` before I read this but its the answer so Its getting up-vote and Correct answer..